# Limit the resources used for a specific SSAS cube

Tags: ssas

I'm wondering if it's possible to limit the CPU/Memory used by a specific SSAS cube.  This needs to be applied to a specific usergroup.  Similar to the Resource Governor we see on SQL Server.

This is primarily to prevent users raising expensive queries.

Best

Lee

Comment: Hi @leehbi https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx ?

Comment: This page is about the Processing operations - I don't have an issue with the cube process, moreover, once the cube is processed users can raise big MDX queries impacting on the whole server.  I'd like to control this if possible.